# Performing a Join without using async in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

My Collection looks like:

```
var followSchema = new Schema({
  facebookId: {type: String, required: true},
  players : [],
});
```

here players[] is an array of id's.

The goal is to obtain this array of ids and then for each Id get full profile information from another collection.

In short this requires a join but since joins don't exist I am using async.

Ofcourse

```
//Step1 : get the players array
 FollowModel.findOne({facebookId: req.user.facebookId}, function(err, result) {

//now for each id in the players array call a function which will make another mongoose call and get details
    async.map(result.players, gatherPlayerDetails, function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      res.send(results);
    });

  });
```

What I don't like about the above solution is that if I am following 200 users, I will make 200 mongoose calls.
If there a way to optimize this query ?

Comment: This does not answer your question but I believe you should have used a different database.

Answer (score 0):

the normal way to do this is `populate` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

in your case:

```
FollowModel.findOne({facebookId:req.user.facebookId})
     .populate('players')
     .exec(function(err, result) {
         // now your players array is filled with full player objects
        ....
      }
```

For this to work you need to add a reference type to your schema:

```
var followSchema = new Schema({
     facebookId: {type: String, required: true},
     players : [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}], 
 });
```